# Can we build APK file for android smart TV from expo React Native?

Tags: expo, apk, android-tv

I am trying to build app for android Tv from expo but when I tried to open app and it gets crash after opening white screen.
I am confused either we can build app for smart TV from expo or not.
Found somewhere that we need to add

```
    "android": {
  "intentFilters": [
    {
      "action": "MAIN",
      "category": [
        "LEANBACK_LAUNCHER"
      ]
    }
  ],
```

}

on App.json but when i try to add it on app.json {expo build:android} shows *build fails!* error.

Comment: Have you checked this out? https://reactnative.dev/docs/building-for-tv

Comment: What is the stacktrace of the crash?

Comment: Yes I have checked that docs but did not get relevant solution for expo.

Comment: I am new in react native. I build .apk file by expo build:android and installed in android TV to test the app. I don't know how to find StackTrace of the crash. Could you please explain how can I get StackTrace?

Comment: You can use `adb logcat` to see the errors provided you have the device connected to your machine with USB debugging enabled or an emulator should work too.